# Weird operator overloading, "operator T& () const noexcept { return *_ptr; }"

Tags: c++, class, c++11

I studied that the format of operator functions is

```
(return value)operator[space]op(arguments){implementation}
```

But, In [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) implementation, there is an operator overloading function declared as `operator T& () const noexcept { return *_ptr; }`.

Is this operator different from `T& operator () const noexcept { return *_ptr; }` ?. If both are different, then what is the use of the first?

Comment: I'm asking what the syntax for creating casting is (as in C# it's eerily similar to this)

Comment: the format is different for conversion operators.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`operator T& () const noexcept;` is a [user-defined conversion function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator). `std::reference_wrapper` has it in order to give you access to the stored reference, without changing the syntax:

```
int x = 42;
int &a = x;
std::reference_wrapper<int> b = x;

std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;
```

<sup>[Assignment is a little bit trickier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463721/assign-a-value-to-a-stdreference-wrapper).</sup>

---

`T& operator () const noexcept;` is an attempt to declare `operator()`, but fails to compile due to missing parameter list. The right syntax would be:

```
T& operator ()( ) const noexcept;
//             ^
//       parameters here
```

and the [usage is completely different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317450/why-override-operator).